# Statements goes back and forth when adding XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputWorkbook);

Tags: java, apache-poi

I added this new line of code to my project.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
```

So I get a red squiggly line underneath
new XSSFWorkbook(inputWorkbook)

So I go to select change input type like in the screenshot

[image]

Then I get another error message when I do the change.

[image]

And it just goes back and forth changing the two lines.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Comment: Try [OPCPackage.open(File)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/OPCPackage.html#open-java.io.File-) ?

Comment: Alternatively, use `WorkbookFactory` - see example [here](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream).

Comment: What can I use for exists in the line `if (inputWorkbook.exists()) `